# Kendo ui grid filed with editor, pop up won´t close

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I have a field on my kendo ui grid which uses an editor:

```
columns:[{ field:"Nome", title: "Nome" },{ field: "idTipoQuarto", title:"Tipo de Quarto", editor: tipoQuartoEditor},
```

In my model i have:

```
schema: 
        {
            data: "data",
            total: function(response) 
            {
              return $(response.data).length;
            },
            model: 
            {
              id: "idQuarto",
              fields: 
              {
                idQuarto: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Nome: { validation: { required: true } },
                idTipoQuarto: { validation: { required: true }}
              }
           }
        }
```

And my editor function is:

```
function tipoQuartoEditor(container, options) 
        {
          $('<input data-text-field="Nome" data-value-field="Nome" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
              autoBind: false,
              dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({

                  transport: 
                  {
                      read:  
                      {
                        url: "data/quartos.php",       
                      },
                      parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
                      {
                          if (operation !== "read" && options.models) 
                          {
                              return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                          }

                      } 
                  },
                  schema: 
                  {
                      data: "data",

                      model: 
                      {
                          id: "idTipoQuarto",
                          value: "Nome"


                      }
                  }
              }) 
          });
        }
```

I can see the values when my popup is opened in the drop-down list, and i can post the selections to my database when clicking on the update/insert button, but the popup won´t disappear. It shows me an error that i don´t understand:

```
Object {xhr: Object, status: "parsererror", errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A, sender: ht.extend.init, _defaultPrevented: false…}
```

What am i missing here, i have seen another post but with no luck adapting to my problem.

Anyone?

Thanks for your time, regards

Comment: After you press Update, and after you take care of business in your API, you need to return the new object that was just updated. This new object needs to be the same type that your kendo schema model accepts. You are most likely not returning the right thing, so kendo cannot parse the object properly.

Comment: What is `data/quartos.php` returning as result of the update? Seems that whatever it returns is not parseable.

Comment: guys, thanks for your help, but my problem was stupid! stupid!, i forgot to delete the print_r from my quartos.php...everything is working now. Thanks for your help gitsitgo and OnaBai.